# Values wont pass- only the null, and update values in the grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

The following is my C# code and aspx code. This code suppose to update a grid on the page, but when I click save it does not pass the value entered in the comment box and update.

```
protected void btnSaveComments_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtRowIndex.Value != string.Empty)
    {
     int gridViewRowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(txtRowIndex.Value);
     txtFlaggedComments.Text = txtFlaggedComments.Text.Replace("'", "`");
     gvSalesmanLicenseList.Rows[gridViewRowIndex].Cells[14].Text = trimComment(txtFlaggedComments.Text, 15);
     gvSalesmanLicenseList.Rows[gridViewRowIndex].Cells[14].ToolTip = txtFlaggedComments.Text; 
     gvSalesmanLicenseList.Rows[gridViewRowIndex].Cells[18].Text = txtFlaggedComments.Text;
     gvSalesmanLicenseList.Rows[gridViewRowIndex].Cells[14].ToolTip.Replace("'", "''");

     LinkButton lblEditComments = (LinkButton)gvSalesmanLicenseList.Rows[gridViewRowIndex].FindControl("lbEditComments");

     lblEditComments.Attributes.Add("onclick", "ShowMyModalPopup('" + gvSalesmanLicenseList.Rows[gridViewRowIndex].RowIndex + "','" + txtFlaggedComments.Text + "')");

     UpdatePanel1.Update();

    }

}
```

And the HTML:

```
<td style="vertical-align: middle; width: 154px; height: 22px; text-align: right" 
    valign="middle" align="right">
    <asp:Button ID="btnPrintSalesmanContinue"OnClick="btnPrintSalesmanContinue_Click"
        runat="server" Text="Submit" __designer:wfdid="w110" CausesValidation="false" 
        UseSubmitBehavior="False></asp:Button>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to access the (first) control of the cell and cast it to the desired WebControl. I'm assuming TextBox or Label.

```
     ((TextBox)gvSalesmanLicenseList.Rows[gridViewRowIndex].Cells[14].Controls[0])).Text = trimComment(txtFlaggedComments.Text, 15);
     ((TextBox)gvSalesmanLicenseList.Rows[gridViewRowIndex].Cells[14].Controls[0])).ToolTip = txtFlaggedComments.Text; 
     ((TextBox)gvSalesmanLicenseList.Rows[gridViewRowIndex].Cells[18].Controls[0])).Text = txtFlaggedComments.Text;
     ((TextBox)gvSalesmanLicenseList.Rows[gridViewRowIndex].Cells[14].Controls[0])).ToolTip.Replace("'", "''");
```